# Unsigned short to byte array

Tags: java, c++, byte, short

I have to send an short as an unsigned short to a TCPServer.

The Problem is that Java doesn't support usigned shorts:
What I have tried:

```
byte[] data = new byte[3];
short port = 5025;

data[0] = 1;
data[1] = (byte)(port & 0xff);
data[2] = (byte)((port >> 8) & 0xff);
```

And this is the way how i convert the data to an unsigned short in C++

```
// Bytes to Short (uint16)
unsigned short port = (data[1] << 8) | data[2];
```

So how can I solve this problem in Java? (I doesn't want to change andything in the C++ Code)

Edit://
My new Java code:

```
byte[] data = new byte[3];
short port = 1151; // short or int doesn't matter in this case

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(5);
buffer.put((byte) 1);
buffer.putShort(port);

out.write(buffer.array());
```

The C++ Code: (the same)

```
unsigned short port = (data[1] << 8) | data[2];
```

I get the right port, if the port is between 0-1151 and 16384-32767, but why doesn't it work with the rest?

Comment: You need to know how numbers work. 1151 = 0x047f. Split that up into two bytes 04 and 7f. Both are positive numbers. 1152 = 0x0480. 04 and 80. 80 is negative (-128) and char is a signed variable so that negative is going to be preserved if resized. `data[1] << 8` is `04<<8` and becomes 0400. Nice. `data[2]` is 80 (-128), but it's about to be combined with a 16 bit number, so it becomes FF80 (-128 in signed 16 bits). `0400|FF80`=FF80 (65408 in unsigned 16 bits). You have to fix the C++ code. It is broken.

Answer (score 3):

It does not matter. Just put it in a `short`. That a `short` is signed is of no concern; a `short` is still 16 bits.

What matters is the endianness here. And if you send over a network, it's big endian.

Which is the default for a `ByteBuffer`, and the default for all numeric primitive types for Java.

So, what do you do? For your particular example, this:

```
// Just for a short...
final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(3);
buf.put((byte) 1);
buf.putShort(myShort);
final byte[] contents = buf.array();
// send the byte[]
```

Now, if you have more to `.put*()` in the `ByteBuffer`, allocate whatever space is necessary etc.

---

HOWEVER. You say you don't want to change anything to your C++ code... Which is not portable across architectures. If you wish to read/write 16 bit values over the network in C++, use `ntohs()/htons()`.

(maybe there are better APIs than that; I haven't done network programming at an advanced level in C/C++ for quite some time)

Comment: Read my answer again. In particular the C++ part.

Comment: But I doesn't want to change anything in C++, because another Client written in C++, is also connecting.

Comment: Yes, and are you guaranteed that all C++ clients will all use CPU architectures with the same endianness? Hint: your C++ program WILL NOT WORK for architectures with different endianness.

Comment: But again: the fact that Java does not have unsigned primitive numeric types is not the problem at all here; your problem is endianness. Try and change the endianness of the ByteBuffer to little endian (hint: that's the .order() method), but by doing this you are basically breaking a basic rule of all things networking, which stipulates that all networking data has to be sent/received in big endian format. The `ntoh*/hton*()` family hasn't been defined this way out of a whim.

Comment: Yes I am sure. On the PCs where I want to use it, it works. :) But I have to find a java solution

Comment: If I use little_endian its not working. I get not the right result.

Comment: That doesn't tell anything. Show the emitting and receiving code in C++ and the emitting/receiving code in Java.

Answer (score 1):

I have a slightly different point of view. The OP is using bit shifting correctly to get into little endian, so the C++ portability will be fine unless he's dealing with a byte of unconventional size. The communication protocol goes against the big endian over network convention, but sometimes supporting legacy systems is like that.

If the port variable has users outside the provided code, use an int and only send the bits you want as you did in your Java sample above. If you are passing that port around, it sucks to keep having to twiddle the damn sign bits and sooner or later you'll screw it up. If no one else needs to play with port, sign isn't going to matter.

```
byte[] data = new byte[3];
int port = 5025; // short or int doesn't matter in this case

data[0] = 1;
data[1] = (byte)(port & 0xff);
data[2] = (byte)((port >> 8) & 0xff);
```

When reading back in and getting 65440, it looks like you used a char and your bytes got sign extended by the shift. Here is a bit of test code so you can play around and see what's happening.

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    unsigned short val = 32896;
    char hi = (char)((val >> 8) & 0xFF);
    char lo = (char)(val &0xFF);
    printf("Watch what the sign bit can do to the bytes here:\n");
    printf("Value: %d, raw in hex: %04x, Hi byte: %02x, Low byte: %02x\n", val, val, hi, lo);



    printf("This one only works if the low byte doesn't sign extend\n");
    char datas[3] = {0, hi, lo};
    unsigned short port = (datas[1] << 8) | datas[2];
    printf("Reassembled short: %u, In Hex: %04x\n", port, port);

    printf("This one works, but will not for an integer\n");
    port = (datas[1] << 8) | (datas[2] & 0xFF);
    printf("Reassembled short: %u, in Hex: %04x\n", port, port);
    unsigned int bigport = (datas[1] << 8) | (datas[2] & 0xFF);
    printf("Reassembled int: %u, in Hex: %04x\n", bigport, bigport);

    printf("With unsigned characters it just works\n");
    unsigned char datau[3] = {0, hi, lo};
    port = (datau[1] << 8) | datau[2];
    printf("Reassembled short: %u, In Hex: %04x\n", port, port);
    bigport = (datau[1] << 8) | (datau[2] & 0xFF);
    printf("Reassembled int: %u, in Hex: %04x\n", bigport, bigport);
}
```

output:

```
Watch what the sign bit can do to the bytes here:
Value: 32896, raw in hex: 8080, Hi byte: ffffff80, Low byte: ffffff80
This one only works if the low byte doesn't sign extend
Reassembled short: 65408, In Hex: ff80
This one works, but will not for an integer
Reassembled short: 32896, in Hex: 8080
Reassembled int: 4294934656, in Hex: ffff8080
This one just works
Reassembled short: 32896, In Hex: 8080
Reassembled int: 32896, in Hex: 8080
```

So what happened?

```
(datas[1] << 8) | datas[2]
```

Both numbers must be scaled up to short and they are signed, so 0x80 becomes 0xFF80. Actually, they become integers, but that's another story.

```
(0xFF80 << 8) | 0xFF80
```

Simplifies to

```
0x8000 | 0xFF80
```

And that ORs to

```
0xFF80
```

AKA 65408, not 32896.

In this case unsigned char is your friend. There may have been problems with the Java, but the C++ is definitely broken.

Comment: Thank you!. But I only receive Port 40975. If I print data[1] and data[2] in C++, I get the following: `ffffffa1 13` The data array in C++ is a type of char. Is that the problem?

Comment: I have change the typ of the array to unsigned char, but there is no difference

Comment: Oh, if I set the bytes to 0xa0 and 0x0f in java everything works fine. So the misstake is in the java code

Comment: Best way to tell is to do what @fge has been asking and edit your question to include more, or all, of the the Java output routine and the C++ input routine. Without that we're shooting in the dark. Have you considered using Wireshark or similar to look at the contents of the data packets to see what is really being sent?